# Display error message in a program I made in c++

Tags: c++

Newbie  in programming.

Want to add a message that say something like wrong input ..
but not sure how to do it.

The program works but want to add error message so the user can't press wrong button

have tried like an if statement inside the while loop like

```
if (input != "A" && input != "a" && input != "S" && input != "s")
cout << "not valid options << endl;
```

and please tell if I can make the code better in any way , always good to know if i am doing things in a good way or not.

here is my code to the program

```
#include <cmath>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    locale swedish("swedish");                          // tar in svenska tecken
    locale::global(swedish);


    int marker = 100;                                       // marker som man börjar med 
    int num1, num2, num3;                                   // numren som ska slumpas senare 
    string input;                                           

    cout << "Välkommen till mitt slumptalspel!!"<< endl ;
    cout << " Detta spel går ut på att man ska få mer än 450" << endl;
    cout << "så får man mer marker och får man mindre än 450 så förlorar man marker" << endl;
    cout << " får man mer än 200 marker så vinner man !!" << endl;
    cout << " och tar markerna slut så har man förlorat" << endl;



    while (input != "A" && input != "a")
    {

        cout << "Du har  " << marker << " marker.  spela tryck [S] avsluta tryck [A]"<< endl;
        cin >>input;                                                            // här bestämmer sig spelaren för om han vill spela eller inte med s eller a
        if (input == "S" || input == "s")
        {

            num1 = rand() % 350 + 1;                                                        // här slumpas talen ut
            num2 = rand() % 350 + 1;
            num3 = rand() % 350 + 1;
            cout << "[" << num1 << "][" << num2 << "][" << num3 << "]" << endl;         // här skrivs num1 till 3 ut vad dom får för värden
            srand(time(0));


            if (num1 + num2 + num3 >= 450)                                              // om väret tillsammans blir mer än 450 
            {
                marker += 12;                                                           // lägg till 12 marker
                cout << "du vann 12 marker =) " << endl;
            }


            else
            {
                cout << " Du förlorade 50 marker" << endl;                                  // annars ta bort 50 marker

                marker -= 50;
            }

            if (marker <= 0)                                                                // om markerna är 0 eller mindre 
            {                                                                                   // så är spelet slut
                cout << " Spelet är slut du har inga marker kvar" << endl;
                return 0;
            }

            if (marker >= 200 )
            {
                cout << " du vann GRATTIS!!" << endl;                       // om man får 200 eller mer marker så vinner man och spelet avslutas sedan
                return 0;
            }


            }




    }
    cout << "Spelet avslutas " << endl;                                                                 // om man avbryter med A så avslutas det så här med detta meddelande
    return 0;
}
```

Did try an switch as someone here said to me, then the problem is that it never stops, when the `marker` is 0 or less or 200  it should stop but it doesent,

I did the code like this

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    locale swedish("swedish");                          // tar in svenska tecken
    locale::global(swedish);


    int marker = 100;                                       // marker som man börjar med 
    int num1, num2, num3;                                   // numren som ska slumpas senare 
    char input;
    int menu();

    cout << "Välkommen till mitt slumptalspel!!" << endl;
    cout << " Detta spel går ut på att man ska få mer än 450" << endl;
    cout << "så får man mer marker och får man mindre än 450 så förlorar man marker" << endl;
    cout << " får man mer än 200 marker så vinner man !!" << endl;
    cout << " och tar markerna slut så har man förlorat" << endl;



    do
    {


        cout << "Du har  " << marker << " marker.  spela tryck [S] avsluta tryck [A]" << endl;
        cin >> input;










        switch (input)
        {


        case 'A':

            cout << " spelet avslutas" << endl;


            return 0;



        case 'S':


            num1 = rand() % 350 + 1;                                                        // här slumpas talen ut
            num2 = rand() % 350 + 1;
            num3 = rand() % 350 + 1;
            cout << "[" << num1 << "][" << num2 << "][" << num3 << "]" << endl;         // här skrivs num1 till 3 ut vad dom får för värden
            srand(time(0));


            if (num1 + num2 + num3 >= 450)                                              // om väret tillsammans blir mer än 450 
            {
                marker += 12;                                                           // lägg till 12 marker
                cout << "du vann 12 marker =) " << endl;
                break;
            }


            else
            {
                cout << " Du förlorade 50 marker" << endl;                                  // annars ta bort 50 marker

                marker -= 50;
                break;
            }

            if (marker <= 0)                                                                // om markerna är 0 eller mindre 
            {                                                                                   // så är spelet slut
                cout << " Spelet är slut du har inga marker kvar" << endl;
                return 0;

            }

            if (marker >= 200)
            {
                cout << " du vann GRATTIS!!" << endl;                       // om man får 200 eller mer marker så vinner man och spelet avslutas sedan


                return 0;
            }






        default:

            cout << " nope inget giltigt val " << endl;                 // Om man väljer ett alternativ som inte finns så kommer detta meddelande fram

            break;



        }
    } while (input != 'q'  )

        ;

}
```

Comment: care to elaborate on `cant make it work`?

Comment: sorry maybe wrong words there. I meant that I cant find a way to make it so the user cant press wrong button . everything else works just fine ..

Comment: Remember to capture the users' first input before your `while` loop. At present you are comparing an uninitialized `string` with `A` and `a` when evaluating the `while` loop conditions for the first time. Using a `switch` statement in your `while` loop, as suggested by Nishant, is a good idea. Perhaps convert all user-input to lower-case or upper-case, to prevent having to check for both cases each time.

Comment: @HvS `input` is an empty string during the first iteration of the `while` loop so there is no problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use switch statements to make it better, and in the `default` case, you can print your desired output:

```
switch(input)
{
case 'A':
 //Do something and break.
case 'a':
 //Do something and break.
.
.
.
default:
cout<<"not valid options" << endl;
}
```

Comment: did the switch case. but then it just took every case . for instance if I press the letter s it just say you lost 50 marker and then it also take the default key message end the program stops. to little letters to put the code in here.. do I have to change the question or can I just put in like answer my own question?

Comment: You can't `switch` on an `std::string`.

Comment: I did change the string to a char

Comment: @Anguiz your edited code is working fine for me, except i can't understand Swedish, so i do not know what you are trying to achieve :(
Otherwise Switch Statement is working fine, another thing i would like to point is Use breaks, instead of return inside Switch Statement, ideally a code should have single entry and single exit point.

Comment: thank you @Nishant  I will remember that! . its just a random number game.if you get more than 450 together of the three random numbers, you get more game chips (marker)otherwise you loose chips, if you get moore than 200 chips you win the game and if its 0 or less you loose. I do have 'return 0' to entrys that you either loose the game or win the game and a or A if you like to abort and quit the game.The case 's' is for spela (play ).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it ,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    locale swedish("swedish");                          // tar in svenska tecken
    locale::global(swedish);


    int marker = 100;                                       // marker som man börjar med 
    int num1, num2, num3;                                   // numren som ska slumpas senare 
    char input;                                         


    cout << "Välkommen till mitt slumptalspel!!" << endl;
    cout << " Detta spel går ut på att man ska få mer än 450" << endl;
    cout << "så får man mer marker och får man mindre än 450 så förlorar man marker" << endl;
    cout << " får man mer än 200 marker så vinner man !!" << endl;
    cout << " och tar markerna slut så har man förlorat" << endl;
    cout << " tre tal kommer att slumpas och varje tal kan vara mellan 1 och 350" << endl;
    cout << " LYCKA TILL!!!" << endl;




    do
    {
        if (marker <= 0)                                                                // om markerna är 0 eller mindre 
        {                                                                                   // så är spelet slut
            cout << " Spelet är slut du har inga marker kvar" << endl;
            return 0;

        }

        if (marker >= 200)
        {
            cout << " du vann GRATTIS!!" << endl;                       // om man får 200 eller mer marker så vinner man och spelet avslutas sedan


            return 0;
        }






        cout << "Du har  " << marker << " marker.  spela tryck [S] avsluta tryck [A]" << endl;
        cin >> input;










        switch (input)
        {


        case 'A':

            cout << " spelet avslutas" << endl;


            return 0;

        case 'a':

            cout << " spelet avslutas" << endl;


            return 0;

        case 'S':


            num1 = rand() % 350 + 1;                                                        // här slumpas talen ut
            num2 = rand() % 350 + 1;
            num3 = rand() % 350 + 1;
            cout << "[" << num1 << "][" << num2 << "][" << num3 << "]" << endl;         // här skrivs num1 till 3 ut vad dom får för värden
            srand(time(0));


            if (num1 + num2 + num3 >= 450)                                              // om väret tillsammans blir mer än 450 
            {
                marker += 12;                                                           // lägg till 12 marker
                cout << "du vann 12 marker =) " << endl;
                break;


            }
            else
            {



                cout << " Du förlorade 50 marker" << endl;                                  // annars ta bort 50 marker

                marker -= 50;
                break;

            }

        case 's':


            num1 = rand() % 350 + 1;                                                        // här slumpas talen ut
            num2 = rand() % 350 + 1;
            num3 = rand() % 350 + 1;
            cout << "[" << num1 << "][" << num2 << "][" << num3 << "]" << endl;         // här skrivs num1 till 3 ut vad dom får för värden
            srand(time(0));


            if (num1 + num2 + num3 >= 450)                                              // om väret tillsammans blir mer än 450 
            {
                marker += 12;                                                           // lägg till 12 marker
                cout << "du vann 12 marker =) " << endl;
                break;


            }
            else
            {



                cout << " Du förlorade 50 marker" << endl;                                  // annars ta bort 50 marker

                marker -= 50;
                break;

            }





        default:

            cout << " nope inget giltigt val försök igen " << endl;                 // Om man väljer ett alternativ som inte finns så kommer detta meddelande fram

            break;



                }
            } while (input != 'QK')

                ;



        }
```